# K9: Marked all mails as read by mistake

Tags: k9-mail

Today I discovered the "Mark all as read" function in K9. I was not very happy to find out, that it marks all mail in my inbox as read even the ones currently not shown on the screen.

Naturally now all my mails in the imap folder are marked as read. Is there any way to undo this? I hit the button not by intention...

P.S. How can anybody wish a shortcut for this feature? :P

Comment: To answer your p.s.: it can be useful if you have a mailing list or similar in a folder. If you have a large backlog of unread mail in the folder (e.g. after getting back from holiday), and you want to ignore it all and start fresh from new mails, mark-all-read is an easy way to do that.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/1194

And there's no way to undo it, sorry.